# Unique Constraint Violated on empty table

Tags: oracle, ora-00001

I recently received a case which my client came across the ORA-00001: unique constraint violated error. This happened when a program tried to truncate two tables and then insert data into them.
From the error-log file, the truncate step was completed, 
delete from INTERNET_GROUP 
delete from INTERNET_ITEM

BUT right after this, the insertion to the Internet_group table triggered the ORA-00001 error. I am wondering if there is any database settings related to this error? I never used Oracle and am wondering if Oracle puts a lock on a row with SELECT statement, in which case the row is locked and not deleted somehow? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: truncate != delete, but probably not relevant. Are you sure it didn't just try to insert multiple clashing rows? The data you're inserting has to be unique within itself, of course, not *just* when compared with existing data. And you're sure the delete wasn't rolled back - have you checked the data in the table after this happened? (It is possible you have a corrupt index or something, but rule out the obvious first)

Comment: can you give a reproducible example?  Or at least the DDL/DML involved?

Comment: Was the delete COMMITed?

Comment: Sounds like a bulk insert thing - where in the same bulk you insert multiple rows with the same key. how do you insert into the tables? do you use "insert as select"?

Answer (score 1):

Please know that there is a difference between truncate and delete. You say you truncated the table, but you mention "delete from" . That is entirely different. 
If you're sure you want to empty the tables, try replacing with

```
truncate table internet_group reuse storage;
```

Mind you that a commit is not necessary with the truncate statement as this is considered a DDL (data definition language) statement and not a DML (Data modification language) statement like updates and deletes.

Also, there is no row locking on selects. But changes are only applied and visible for other sessions in the database when commit-ed. 
I guess that is wat happened; you deleted the records but did not execute a commit (yet) and subsequently inserted new records.

edit:
I now realize you're probably inserting multiple records....
The other option might be, that the data itself causes a violation. Can you please provide the constraints on the table? There must be a primary key or unique constraint. You might want to hold that against your dataset.